# how to store key and value in ehcache3 using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache-3

I want to store key and value in ehcache3 using springboot. 
     I want to store key as "passportNumber" and value as "name" similar to a 
      Hashmap in java
     And later once it is cached, how to retrieve the value from 
     passportNumber.

I am new to `ehcache-3` and I need some code. I don't find anything example on the site nor by googing it.

Comment: I want to store key and value in ehcache3 using springboot. 
     I want to store key as "passportNumber" and value as "name" similar to a 
      Hashmap in java
     And later once it is cached, how to retrieve the value from 
     passportNumber.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't go for ehcache 3.x because many of the features are available
>   with only paid once. Better go for versions below ehcache 3.x.

**Read this doc for Ehcache - Spring Implementation :**

```
https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/spring.html
```

**Read this doc for how to use ehcache in java:**

`https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html#using-caches`

**Read this doc for how to configure ehcache:**

```
https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration.html
```

Many examples are present for ehcache + Spring Boot. Please search it.